# How to set the range of each Dropdown graph using plot.ly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph with 4 subplots which I can select using a Dropdown menu.

I'm trying to add these "fillings" (`fill='tonexty'`) into the plots, but whenever I add them, the yaxis who was previously autoscaled and started at 110 for example, gets rescaled to start from 0. I want its range to be autoscaled as it was previous to adding the "filling".

Check the images below to see the "before" and "after" adding the filling into the graph:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I've tried adding `autorange=True` to the graph's layout but it did not work.

You can check my layout below.

```
layout = go.Layout(
            title="Cotação do Café em Dólares Americanos (U$)",
            xaxis=dict(
                title="Período",
                titlefont=dict(
                    family='Courier New, monospace',
                    size=18,
                    color='#7f7f7f'
                )
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title="Valor U$",
                autorange=True,
                titlefont=dict(
                    family='Courier New, monospace',
                    size=18,
                    color='#7f7f7f'
                )
            ),
            updatemenus=list([
                dict(
                    buttons=list([
                        dict(
                            args=['visible', [True, False, False, False]],
                            label='Variação Anual',
                            method='restyle'
                        ),
                        dict(
                            args=['visible', [False, True, False, False]],
                            label='Variação Semestral',
                            method='restyle'
                        ),
                        dict(
                            args=['visible', [False, False, True, False]],
                            label='Variação Mensal',
                            method='restyle'
                        ),
                        dict(
                            args=['visible', [False, False, False, True]],
                            label='Variação Semanal',
                            method='restyle'
                        )
                    ]),
                )
            ]),
        )
```

Here is the `Scatter` of  the plots, this is where I added the    filling:

```
trace_max = go.Scatter(
            y = lista_precos_max,
            x = lista_datas_max,
            fill='tonexty',
            line=go.Line(color='blue')
        )
        trace_semestre = go.Scatter(
            y = lista_precos_semestre,
            x = lista_datas_semestre,
            visible = False,
            fill='tonexty',
            line=go.Line(color='orange')

        )
        trace_mes = go.Scatter(
            y = lista_precos_mes,
            x = lista_datas_mes,
            fill='tonexty',
            visible = False,
        )
        trace_semana = go.Scatter(
            y = lista_precos_semana,
            x = lista_datas_semana,
            fill='tonexty',
            visible = False,
        )
```

Comment: you have not provided the complete code for layout,  as to how you have implemented the dropdown, have you used the tutorials [Simple Dropdown Menu](https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/) to do this? can you give the complete layout so that I can check it?

Comment: @NarenMurali Yes. That's what I used to write my code, I'll post the whole layout as soon as I can

Comment: Sorry I missed something, after seeing the layout I understand that you want to see all the graphs set to 'tonexty' with a yaxis value of 110. To the best of my knowledge, tonexty will always have the xaxis start from 0. I have tried another issue similar to this. I tried to start the date range from 00:00 to 23:00, but I was not able to do it, if you wanna know the reason immediately go to plotly page on github and raise an issue.